# Error in using fzero

Tags: matlab

I am trying to solve a non-linear equation by using a while loop in Matlab but it's not giving me the results and give me an error in line that uses fzero function.

Why does this happens? How to solve the issue? Could someone help me with this?
Thanks in advance.

```
function z=optp(z,p)
    z=3.067;
    p=0;
    while (z-p) > 0.8
        syms a y Q p
        p=z;
        w=3;
        C=1;
        P=5;
        b=1.2;
        c=8;
        B=0.5;
        R=A^B*c*p^-b;
        Q=(0.5-1/(p+5))*2400*((A^0.5)/(p^(6/5)));
        x=Q;
        J1=int(int(a*x*0.01,y,a*x/R,100),a,0,Q/x);
        J2=(b*x^2*0.01/R)*int(a^2*1,a,0,Q/x);
        J3=(P*R*b/p)*(int(int(y*0.01,y,a*x/R,100),a,0,Q/x));
        J4=(b*R^2/x)*int(y^2*0.01,y,0,Q/R);
        J5=(R*0.2)*(int(int(y*0.01,a,y*R/x,1),y,0,Q/R));
        J=J1+J3+J4-J2-J5;
        z=fzero(@ (p) J,p)
    end
end
```

Comment: Could you please try to make the code smaller?  Perhaps use a smaller equation?  You will probably get a better answer if the code is reduced down to the minimum amount to cause the error (5 lines would be ideal, less then 10 would be acceptable).

Comment: Your function is constant, it always returns J ignorieren the parameter p

Comment: @GuySchalnat: thanks for your tips..ok I try to make it smaller

Comment: @Daniel: thanks for your opinion,but i don't think so.

Comment: The function handle never uses the input p. That a local variable in your function handle and it is different to the p you defined above. Unfortunately I don't understand what you want to implement, otherwise I would have told you how to do it.

Comment: @Daniel:this function is a small component of a wider code,and  tries to improve the amount of p and makes it closer to the optimum p.